# Laravel Pagination works only on the first page

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-pagination, laravel-paginate

Code in this function is executed by ajax call.
I have pagination like this:

```
{
    $id=$_GET['data'];
    User::where('votes', '>', $id)->paginate(15);
}
```

It works fine on the first page, however on the second page it does not find the $_GET['data'].
   How can I organize the pagination in this case?
   Do I have to overwrite the pagination for this case to enable an extra GET parameter pass to that?
Thanks much in advance :)

Comment: this might help you : https://gist.github.com/tobysteward/6163902

Comment: When you look at the links on the view which get generated by the paginator, do they contain the get variables?

Comment: Don't use `$_GET['data']` , it's better to use Laravel syntax like `$request->input('data')` or `Input::get('data')`.

Comment: Can you put more code?

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you will have something like this to show the pagination:

```
{!! $users->links() !!}
```

To pass your other parameters with it, you should change it into:

```
{!! $users->appends(Request::only('data))->links() !!}
```